# How to use a symbolic link to use emacs in Mac OS

Tags: macos, unix, emacs, symlink

I want to create a command line executable which will spawn an emacs window/application.
I searched on the internet and found that the emacs shipped with Mac is not supported in X11 window So, I downloaded the latest emacs from http://emacsformacosx.com/ and installed it in my mac.
Then I go to the /usr/bin directory and create a symbolic link like this:

```
sudo ln /Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs xemacs
```

when I run this symblolic link by ./xemacs it says(. means /usr/bin):

> Warning: arch-dependent data dir
>   (/Users/david/src/emacs-dev/ftp-versions/emacs-24.2/nextstep/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS//libexec/emacs/24.2/x86_64-apple-darwin/)
>   does not exist. Warning: arch-independent data dir
>   (/Users/david/src/emacs-dev/ftp-versions/emacs-24.2/nextstep/Emacs.app/Contents/Resources/share/emacs/24.2/etc/)
>   does not exist. Error: charsets directory not found:
>   /Users/david/src/emacs-dev/ftp-versions/emacs-24.2/nextstep/Emacs.app/Contents/Resources/share/emacs/24.2/etc/charsets
>   Emacs will not function correctly without the character map files.
>   Please check your installation!

But if I run the Emacs binary in directory /Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/ it starts the application without any error.

Any one knows how to solve this problem?

Comment: I imagine it examines `argv[0]` to find its resources. You might have to use a script instead of a symlink.

Comment: By the by, `xemacs` in general refers to a fork project, not GNU Emacs. For your own private use, this is completely harmless, of course, but I thought I'd still point out the potential for a mix-up.

Comment: ... Or, symlink to `/Applications/Emacs.app`? Why do you want a symlink, anyway; isn't Emacs in your `PATH`?

Comment: @tripleee Emacs.app is a directory. “emacs” is taken by Mac-shipped version of emacs. Sure I can add the /Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/ to PATH, but I hate type Capital Emacs :(

Comment: Put the symlink in `/usr/local/bin` instead; you should not be messing with the system `/usr/bin` anyway, and that way, you can also call it `emacs` if you like.

Comment: If it is only the capital letter, you could use an alias: `alias emacs="open -a Emacs"`

Comment: Another alternative is to start emacs in daemon mode (`Emacs --daemon`) and symlink `/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/emacsclient`.  This has the added advantage of using one persistent session.

Comment: For what it's worth, I got similar diagnostics when I tried to symlink `/Applications/Dictionary.app/Contents/MacOs/Dictionary`.  What worked was creating a script containing `open /Applications/Dictionary.app` (yes, the directory containing the application bundle).  But +1 for @Matthias' suggestion to just use an alias.

Comment: Well, up to this point, I think the best way is to create an executable script in /usr/etc   Unless there're other alternatives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Up to this point I think the best way is to create an executable script under /usr/bin which will execute the binary file /Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs. The reason I didn't use "open" command is that I need to use some Emacs binary arguments. Compared to "open" this method can spawn multiple instance of emacs.

The script is :

```
#! /bin/sh
/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs "$@"
```

Then make it executable by doing chmod +x script.sh

then make the symlink

ln -s "/usr/local/bin/script.sh" /usr/local/bin/xemacs

Comment: Again, the proper place for local scripts is `/usr/local/bin`. The system could wipe all of `/usr/bin` in an upgrade.

Comment: That script is:`#! /bin/sh
/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs "$@"` (with a newline after the `/bin/sh`).

Comment: This is what I've been doing for months, but I've never understood what bug in Emacsformacosx causes the issue in the first place.

Comment: You could use just one executable file without any symlinks, whatever. The only difference is instead of creating symlinks just create `xemacs` file with a shebang plus a reference as you mentioned and set executable flag `chmod +x xemacs`

Answer (score 2):

You could use an alias: `alias emacs="open -a Emacs --args <youroptions>`.
The option `--args` allows you to pass options directly to emacs (e.g., `-q` avoids the evaluation of the init script).